# How can I install the KY-001 temperature sensor on my Raspberry Pi 2 B?

Tags: sensor, temperature, breadboard

I'm a beginner and know basically nothing about Raspberry Pi. Recently I bought a sensor kit and a breadboard, but there are no tutorials for them.
So how can I, for example, install a temperature sensor?
This is my setup:

- Raspberry Pi 2 B
- [A Breadboard](http://www.conrad.de/ce/de/product/1341733/Entwickler-Platine-Bread-SET-Banana-Pi-Cubieboard-Raspberry-Pi-Raspberry-Pi-A-B-B-pcDuino?ref=searchDetail)
- A KY-001 temperatur sensor module

Details about the sensor:

- Chipset: DS18B20
- communication protocol: 1-Wire
- 9- 12Bit accurate temperature measurement in the range of -55 ° C to + 125 ° C

[image]

Comment: I'd start by typing DS18B20 in the search box and then reading the relevant posts.

Comment: In addition to @joan's comment you could also look at this https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing from adafruit. I would suggest that in future when buying parts and kits it  is generally a good idea to spend a little more money to get full documentation, datasheet and software from sites like adafruit- especially for newbies.